# update routes dynamically in angular2 app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on an application where I load modules dynamically based on a json. i want to update the app routing based on what modules the use have permission to see. How do I achieve this in angular2 final release.

Answer (score 1):

Did you checkout guards https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards ?

This allow restricting loading module route...

Comment: Guards will not help in my use case. In my app. The app will not have any routes for the sub apps it's going to host at the start, its only when it loads a json or hits an api, it knows about the subapps. At this point, I would want to update the routes.

`router.resetConfig` might work, but I should also be able to refresh when I am inside a subapp.

Comment: in deed resetConfig might be the solution. Did you tried it ? However i wouldn't do such thing and use router capability with guard instead of dynamic routing.